# Is this layout possible in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

This layout seems simple but I can't find any way to do this solely in xml using `LinearLayout` or any other layout without changing properties dynamically. Here is what I want, if text is short then layout should be totally wrapped as shown in figure:

[image]

But in case `TextView` contains longer text then it should be expanded but it must leave space for `Button` like this:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about what are you looking for.. but it seems a layout width of wrap content for the text view will do it

Comment: Simple layout width of wrap content will push the button out of the view if we are using `LinearLayout`.

Comment: in `TextView` use `android:singleLine=true` and `android:elipesize=end` and set the button to `android:toTheRightOf` *TextView*

Comment: @MuhammadBabar It wont cater the first scenario when text is short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After experimenting a lot of layout, the best that I can do is to use `TableLayout` with `shrinkColumns`

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="0" >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="This is a very long text and it cannot be displayed wholly" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Lolz nice one. Never felt the need to use `TableLayout` before this. +1;

Comment: There is a better way to achieve this since ConstraintLayout came out, please check  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60163899/826606

Or the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164080/826606

Answer (score 0):

make width of textview `wrapcontent` and give button `toRightOf` text view
then text view will expand according to the text,and button will be always to right of text view

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="400dp"
        android:text="what ever you want" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tV"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: This will simply push the button out of the view if text is long.

Comment: no you can provide fixed width to button and and align it to parentright=true

Comment: This is even worst. Not even it pushes the `Button` out of view if text is long but also if text is short then `Button` is expanded to fill remaining space. Have you event tried it?  Please read the question again and try to understand what I am asking.

Comment: sorry my mistake,see my update answer i have added maxwidth property that will not let textview to expand more than thiat @M-WaJeEh

Comment: this will definetly solve your problem,upvote this and mark this as answer for others help thankyou @M-WaJeEh

Comment: Hold your horses !! I guess you are not understanding my question. First of all what about those screens who have more width than 400dp? and Secondly it is still not catering my first scenario neither it is catering second scenario. If text is short button fills the screen but if text is long button is out of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Wajeeh ........................

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:text="kdfjdk" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is via `ConstraintLayout` which wasn't available when this question was posted. Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60163899/826606

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="April Ludgate April April "
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/threadType"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threadType"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text="SMS"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```