# Simple yet tricky layout using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make the following seemingly simple yet tricky layout using `ConstraintLayout`.

**Normal UI:**
[image]

**With longer title:**

[image]

**I have tried following code:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="April Ludgate"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/threadType"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threadType"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:text="SMS"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dummy"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/date"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/threadType"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4:18 PM"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dummy"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Which give me this:**

[image]

**But quickly fall apart with a longer name:**

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this via `ConstraintLayout` just in xml? I am willing to switch to another layout if it accomplished what I want.

Comment: Why not try character count programmatically and add those dots if it exceeds the limit?

Comment: You should try linear layout

Comment: it's not tricky, it's just a bad design. if SMS is a label then why it's floating around with text?  As i think, users have tendency to look at the same place for labels, if label is floating then user have to look at whole row to just identify it's a SMS.

Comment: @AshwiniViolet This is not a question about UX or Graphic Designing. I have a layout that I want to achieve in Android.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh that's why it's just a comment, not an answer, i don't think anything bad in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `constraintHorizontal_chainStyle` to **packed** in *title* with `constraintHorizontal_bias` to **0.0** like below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="April Ludgate April Ludgate April Ludgate April Ludgate"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/threadType"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threadType"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text="SMS"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/date"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4:18 PM"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output:**

- Short Text

[image]

- Long Text

[image]

Comment: Wow Amazing... Didn't even think about using packed chain type.